# Custom request/response format in netty-socket-io

Tags: java, json, websocket, socket.io, netty

When I send request it looks like (Google Chrome Console) :

```
42/v1/user,["currentPerson",{"transactionId":"53445t-53454-534543-53453435"}]
```

where `53445t-53454-534543-53453435` - is unique transactionId which I automatically include in request and each response.

The response looks like

```
42/v1/user,["currentPerson","53445t-53454-534543-53453435",{"id":5,"firstName":"Ivan"}]
```

where `/v1/user` - namespace with versioning;

1) I don't want the 42. And don't want array on top-level
2) I just want such kind of response

```
{
    "transactionId": "53445t-53454-534543-53453435",
    "namespace": "/v1/user",
    "event": "currentPerson",
    "person": {
        "id": 5,
        "firstName": "Ivan"
    }
}
```

3) And such kind of request

```
{
    "transactionId": "53445t-53454-534543-53453435",
    "namespace": "/v1/user",
    "event": "currentPerson"
}
```

Now I use socket-io js client but only for test purposes, service will be used with using some C++ library, so I need to use not the socket.io style format.

Is it possible? What methods can I use?

I have found `addJsonObjectListener` method and `sendJsonObject`, but they was removed in 1.7.0 and anyway I don't want to pass a `@class` directive, it seems weird to me to give client a knowledge about server class hierarchy. I just want define some object on the client and parse it manually on the server, then pass manually formed json to the client.

P.S.: By the way `Configuration.jsonTypeFieldName` is not available now, so `@class` now is the only option of name.

netty-socket-io 1.7.7

Comment: I'm not familiar to socket.io's protocol aspect and netty-socket-io but basically if you won't use socket.io style format, why do you use or test socket.io?

Comment: @Donghwan Kim: It is the first time when I develope in osgi. And first time with websockets. I need a library with osgi-integration (preferably on netty). I have found spring websockets, but it contains a lot of complex dependencies, too hard to integrate in osgi. Netty-socket-io is integrated fine and works like a charm but I was completely sure that format of messages may be customized. If not the next candidate to integration is nettosphere. Could you give an advice? Is nettosphere a good choice? Do you have an experience with osgi and nettosphere?What other websocket libraries do you know?

Comment: I don't know osgi but here's some advices I can give you about writing real-time application. First, decide whether to use vanilla WebSocket that is a pure implementation of WebSocket protocol specified by RFC or some higher protocol on top of WebSocket that provides useful patterns to write real-time webapp by hiding low-level details and considers when WebSocket is not available.

Comment: For the former, [Netty](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/package-summary.html) and [Java WebSocket API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html) implementations like [Tyrus (RI)](https://tyrus.java.net/) are available. For the latter, netty-socket-io, [Atmosphere (Nettosphere)](https://github.com/atmosphere/atmosphere) and [Cettia](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/) are available. Of course, you will need the corresponding C++ client implementation of the protocol you decided.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to convert Json response in String and send it as String.

```
String json = convertInString(json);
buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(json, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

ctx.write(a);
```

Comment: Mikhail: it is interesting! But how can I get ChannelHandlerContext in high-level abstraction's netty-socket-io listener? I have only SocketIOClient, no Netty objects. Or I need to write custom PacketEncode/PacketDecoder? But how instantiate it after overriding?

Comment: @Ivan you may extends `SocketIOChannelInitializer` and override anything you want